# C# how to display DataGridView column header into textbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, textbox, header

How to display a column header into text box when I select a specific cell in the DataGridView ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int idx = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;
this.textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.Columns[idx].HeaderText;
```